Mocking SupabaseClient's rpc Method with Mockito in Dart
I'm trying to mock the SupabaseClient class in my Dart project to verify that the rpc method is called with the correct parameters. I’m using the Mockito package for this, but I'm running into an issue with the overridden rpc method.
Here's the overridden rpc method I have:
@override
_i2.PostgrestFilterBuilder<T> rpc<T>(
  String? fn, {
  Map<String, dynamic>? params,
}) =>
    (super.noSuchMethod(
      Invocation.method(
        #rpc,
        [fn],
        {#params: params},
      ),
      returnValue: _FakePostgrestFilterBuilder_7<T>(
        this,
        Invocation.method(
          #rpc,
          [fn],
          {#params: params},
        ),
      ),
      returnValueForMissingStub: _FakePostgrestFilterBuilder_7<T>(
        this,
        Invocation.method(
          #rpc,
          [fn],
          {#params: params},
        ),
      ),
    ) as _i2.PostgrestFilterBuilder<T>);

To facilitate the mocking, I've also mocked the PostgrestFilterBuilder class. My test setup looks like this:
void main() {
  final MockSupabaseClient supabase = MockSupabaseClient();
  final MockPostgrestFilterBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> postgrestFilterBuilder = MockPostgrestFilterBuilder();
  final RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource = RemoteDataSourceImpl(supabase: supabase);

  test('fetch quiz items test', () async {
    when(
      supabase.rpc<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>('get_exams_by_topic', params: {'topic_param': 'topic'})
    ).thenAnswer((realInvocation) => postgrestFilterBuilder);

    await remoteDataSource.fetchQuizItems(topic: 'topic');

    verify(supabase.rpc('get_exams_by_topic', params: {'topic_param': 'topic'}));
  });
}

However, I encountered the following error during the test:
MissingStubError: 'then'
No stub was found which matches the arguments of this method call:
then(Closure: (List<Map<String, dynamic>>) => dynamic, {onError: Closure: (Object, StackTrace) => dynamic})

How can I properly mock the rpc method of the SupabaseClient class to avoid this MissingStubError? What adjustments do I need to make to ensure that the mocked method returns the correct type?
